# Eclipse equivalent command in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I am switch to Intellij from Eclipse.
I would like to know if/what is the equivalent in Intellij

1. Quick Fix (Control-1 in eclipse)
2. In editor for the file which I open, navigate the Project/Directory window to show the same file?
3. Highlight a section of code and do 'correct indentation'

Comment: Well done! Since I moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ 4 years ago, I never looked back!

Comment: 3: I recommend the setting "Reformat on paste: Reformat block" found under Settings -> Editor -> Smartkeys (IntelliJ IDEA 10.5)

Comment: The title would almost be bad, except this is definitely the first equivalent you can't find but look for.

Answer (score 16):

Ad. 1: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Ad. 2: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, select "*1. Project view*"

Ad. 3: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Also for (2), you can check "Autoscroll to source" on the project view, and it will keep your views on sync.

Comment: For 1. (Quick fix) Maybe I'm missing something but Alt-Enter is approaching, but not equivalent. For example, selecting a block of code, and IIUC hitting Alt-enter does not propose Refactor/Extract Method as it would in Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

I'm unsatified with the answer that <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a match for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> provides shortcuts to generate code depending on what you are doing. For example, if you are on a method it can generate code for a local field based on the return type.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> ... generates a local variable based on the return type of a method which I'd say is one my main uses of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a Mac:

1: <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

2: <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, select "*1. Project view*"

3: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>